# Cocos 2d-x: align menu left

Tags: c++, user-interface, cocos2d-x

Menu by default center menu items within the menu, but i want menu with left alignment, like on screenshot.

[image]

How can i create left-aligned menu? Thanks.

UPD:
this is how i create menu:

```
    cocos2d::MenuItemFont::setFontSize(FONT_SIZE_ITEMS);
cocos2d::MenuItemFont::setFontName(FONT_NAME);

auto pMenu = Menu::create(
    MenuItemFont::create("How To Play", CC_CALLBACK_1(BMSettingsLayer::onHowToPressed, this)),
    this->soundMenuItem(),
    this->musicMenuItem(),
    MenuItemFont::create("Buy Lives",CC_CALLBACK_1(BMSettingsLayer::onBuyLivesPressed, this)),
    MenuItemFont::create("Remove Ads", CC_CALLBACK_1(BMSettingsLayer::onRemoveAdsPressed, this)),
    MenuItemFont::create("Rates",CC_CALLBACK_1(BMSettingsLayer::onRatesPressed, this)),
    MenuItemFont::create("Contact",CC_CALLBACK_1(BMSettingsLayer::onContactsPressed, this)),
    nullptr);

pMenu->setPosition(Point(winSize.width * 0.55, winSize.height*0.5));
pMenu->alignItemsVertically();
pMenu->setColor(Color3B::BLACK);
this->addChild(pMenu);
```

Comment: Show some code. AFAIK nodes (so also `MenuItems` are not arragned by `Menu` automatically. Explain your problem in more detail please.

Comment: You need to use `setPosition()` on your menu items.